# parallel write and read from file

Tags: java, file, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to have a central log file in my system, to which a certain application can write and read from.
The writes are for new data, and the reads will be to compare generated data to written data.
I would like this application to run in multiple instances at a time, which means I need to find a way to read diffs from the file, and write.
I have seen this code, but it's good for one go over the file and I don't see it working in multiple instances.
I'm building this app as a command line tool, so I'm thinking about creating a file for each instance and them migrating it to the "general" log file.
I'd like to hear inputs from the forum regarding the different approaches to this question.
What I'm worried about is having a few instances reading and writing from the same file and generating a lock.
This is the code I have found so far:

```
public class Tp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File f = new File("/path/to/your/file/filename.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader(f));
    bw.write("Some text");
    bw.flush();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    bw.write("Some more text");
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: try using log4j

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying writing and reading the same file not only in one program but even within one thread. I do not believe this would be of benefit as during the program you know when/what you wrote so you can get rid of the whole I/O logic.

In the beginning try to write two different programs that run as separate processes. If need be, you can still try to bring them into the same JVM as separate threads.

Writing for sure is no problem, so the more interesting part is the reading logic. I'd probably implement this algorithm:

- Loop until the program is terminated...

  - open the file, use skip() to jump to the location with new data
  - consume the existing data
  - remember how many bytes were read/remember the file size
  - close the file
  - wait until file has changed

Waiting for the file to change can be done by monitoring [File.lastModified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) or [File.length](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#length()), or using the [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).

But be aware if you have multiple applications writing to the same file in parallel it can break any meaningful structure you have in the data. Log4j ensures parallel writes from within one application/multiple threads will go correctly into the file. If you need multiple processes running synchronized writes, consider logging into a database.